# cypress: reload until label comes up

Tags: cypress

How do I reload page until a label appears on screen?
I am currently trying this, but not working:

```
cy.get("body").reload().should("contain", success ? "Success" : "Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best way to have conditional testing, but this should work:

```js
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  if ($body.find('<ERROR_ELEMENT>').length === 1) {
    cy.reload()
  }
})
```

Ofcourse you need to replace `<ERROR_ELEMENT>` with the actual element.